# I do not know how to store json data from an api call within a nodejs express server, and send it to a react native client

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, express

I am running a node js server with an app.js that looks like this:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require("cors");
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
testAPIRouter= require("./routes/testAPI");
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use("/testAPI", testAPIRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I am trying to make a call to an igdb api from my server and store the json contents of that request, then route it to the client. My code for the routed request looks like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');

axios({
    url: "https://api.igdb.com/v4/covers",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Client-ID' : '**********',
        'Authorization' : '***********',
    },
    data: "fields alpha_channel,animated,checksum,game,height,image_id,url,width;"
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    const testing = response.data;
    })
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    });


router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.send("API is working properly");
    res.json(testing);
    
    
});



module.exports = router;
```

When connecting to my server on postman and making a request, I get the message that my API is working correctly which is expected, but the json data is not returned. I know that my API post request is formatted correctly because the json is logging to the terminal of my server, followed by this error message:

> GET /testAPI 200 4.002 ms - 23
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
>     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCodes\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)

If anyone can help the right way to transfer the json data from my api call within the server to a client, that would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you tried putting the axios request inside the get-route callback function? The axios request seems to be made whenever you start the node server and testing should be undefined when you're making a get request to that route.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send either [res.send](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-send) or [res.json](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-json).
Both of the function are setting a header.

```
res.send("API is working properly");
res.json(testing);
```

So just use

```
res.json(testing);
```